# geom_area multiple plot error

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
data1 <- seq(1, 300, 3)
data2 <- seq(1, 100, 0.5)
acf1 <- acf(data1, plot = F, lag.max = 25)
acf2 <- acf(data2, plot = F, lag.max = 25)
df<- data.frame(lag = acf1$lag,acf1=acf1$acf,acf2=acf2$acf)
colnames(df)<-c("lag","data1","data2")
data<-melt(df,id="lag")
ggplot(data, aes(x=lag, y=value)) +
geom_area(aes(colour = variable, fill= variable),position="dodge")
```

[image]

I want to display both of the `Acf` values by two different color, but I can't figure out why it only displays one color. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its actually there but hidden by the `data2` block , use alpha(transparency) to see it, I have also changed your dodge option a bit like below.

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=lag, y=value)) +
  geom_area(aes(colour = variable, fill= variable),position = position_dodge(width = 0.5), alpha = 0.5)
```

If you start changing the width of `position_dodge` and `alpha` , you will see the these blocks in much better way.

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, PKumar, but does it has any solution that make the overlap part be red , just like the other question which I asked  here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50388967/multiple-ggacf-plot-in-r

Comment: @Xiaol.Song, just increase, like I mentioned in the answer,  'position_dodge(width = 0.5)' to let say 50, your overlap will change.you will see more red than cyan.

Comment: I edit my question again, and I expect the ggplot could be like the second one.

Comment: @Xiaol.Song , Two things:1) please never ever change a question, now you have made my existing answer worthless. If you want to solve a separate question, ask a separate one.  2) If I write my solution and then you change your question again? All of this go in vein. Write a problem which you actually want to solve, please read this, its called xy problem: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Thanks for your reminding, that's exactly my situation. I will ask by the other question.